# How to check if a variable has any character or not?

Tags: php

I am tring to parse the .CSV file into the sql table.
If the name in the .CSV file has no character than it should pass NULL value into sql table .
below is the coe that i am using.

```
 $name = $data[0];
 $email= $data[1];
 if($name !== /[a-zA-Z]/)
 {
      $name == NULL;
 }
```

please tell me what wrong with this code

Comment: `if($name != '')
 {
      $name == NULL;
 }`

Comment: I think sql will automatically convert undefined/not defined etc to null

Comment: my sql table show blank space it does not take  NULL automatically

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're checking if name equals the regular expression. While there are languages that allow you to shortcut regexp matching using one operator (Ruby, for example), PHP doesn't have this functionality (at least yet), and to check if string matches regular expression you have to use one of the `preg_*` family functions:

```
if (!preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $name)) {
    $name = null;
}
```

Please also note that regular expression is in fact just a string and is quoted - PHP hasn't separate variable type for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

== used to compare not for assigning values we can try following for same to save data in MYSQL

```
$name = null;

 $name="NULL"
```